# Apache Flink - Rescale a job whilst respecting max parallelism

Tags: apache-flink

I have a flink job like this:

```
DataStream<SomeObject> input1 = environment.addSource(mySource()).setParallelism(1).setMaxParallelism(1);
DataStream<SomeObject> input2 = environment.addSource(mySourceTwo());

input1.union(input2)
      .map(doSomething())
      .output(outputSomething());
```

So one operator must stay with a parallelism of 1 while others can be as high as needed.

When I rescale the job using the Rest API (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/monitoring/rest_api.html) I get an error because it tries to rescale all operators.

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Cannot rescale vertex Source: Scheduled BookingSignals because its maximum parallelism 1 is smaller than the new parallelism 3.
```

Is it possible to rescale flink jobs via the REST api without trying to rescale operators higher than their max parallelism?

Comment: What if you remove `setMaxParallelism`? Won't it still use the operator-specific parallelism you configured (1) and not the one from the job (3)?

Comment: @gcandal I would've thought it would work like that but no, it will actually scale the operator. (to 3 in this example)